# Qt4iOS XCode can`t find QUIWebView class

Tags: ios, xcode

While trying to build the fancybrowser (Qt4iOS SDK) example project in XCode, the linker can`t find the class QUIWebView calls.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "QUIWebView::evaluateJavaScript(QString const&)"
  "QUIWebView::load(QUrl const&)"
  "QUIWebView::setHtml(QString const&, QUrl const&)"
  "QUIWebView::QUIWebView(QWidget*)"
  "QUIWebView::pageAction(QUIWebView::WebAction) const"
  "QUIWebView::networkAccessManager() const"
  "QUIWebView::url() const"
  "QUIWebView::title() const"
```

Please, could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

That error message means that he linker can't find the functions listed. You are missing either the source file or the library where they are defined.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response! Hi did everything from scratch and it worked.